# java generic method for all enums ! enumType problem

Tags: java

**I want to implement this generic methode for all my enums , but i can't get the enumType ??**

```
public static <T extends Enum> T getValue(String value) throws ValidationException {
    try {
        Class<T> enumType = null; //i can't get it ????
        return (T) T.valueOf(enumType, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ValidationException(ERROR_CODE.ERR_INVALID_PARAM);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. You have to accept an extra `Class<T>` parameter.

Comment: Ok thanks  I'll add it like parameter.

Comment: @Sweeper but then you may as well just invoke `Enum.valueOf(clazz, value)` directly.

Comment: BTW: `<T extends Enum<T>>`

Answer (score 1):

Java's generics system uses an approach called "type erasure". This means that the type parameters, such as `T`, only exist in the source code, not the actual compiled program. As such, there is no way to know what type `T` represents when the method is called since the whole notion of `T` doesn't even exist during runtime.

Unfortunately, the only way for the method to get a `Class<T>` instance is to actually pass it as a parameter:

```java
MyEnum e = getValue(MyEnum.class, "MY_VALUE");
```

Once you have the `Class<T>` instance, you can call the `getEnumConstants()` method on it to get an array of all the enum values. You can then search through it for the value with the desired name:

```java
T[] constants = enumType.getEnumConstants();
for (T c : constants) {
    if (c.name().equals(value)) {
        return c;
    }
}
throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such value: " + value);
```